# fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory when compiling caffe

Tags: opencv, caffe

I kept getting this error:

```
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto 
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
CXX src/caffe/layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/blob.cpp
CXX src/caffe/syncedmem.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp
src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
1 | #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:525: .build_release/src/caffe/data_transformer.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand where I go wrong. I'm using OpenCV  4.4.0 but it kept saying fatal error on opencv2. I also have installed all the dependencies that needed. does anyone have any idea about it? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your opencv is correctly compiled and installed, it should be just a redundant directory. There is a directory opencv2 in the directory named opencv4, and then the specific classification file. That's what caffe compiling needs and why it kept saying fatal error on opencv2.

Solution: Put the entire copy of the opencv2 folder under the directory /usr/local/include/opencv4, and put it in the upper directory /usr/local/include, to compile Caffe normally (although there are other problems).

I encountered the same problem in the Ubuntu18 system with opencv4.2.0. It seems that opencv4 is too high to compile caffe. If you go on with it, there will be more errors because of it. I suggest you compile caffe with cuda8 and opencv3.X.